# Payment system - in Europe

Tags: php, paypal, payment, payment-processing

I need a simple online payment system available for Europe. I'm thinking at PayPal as a solution. Any other recommendations?

Comment: Define "Europe"... Apart from being off-topic, this also has *way* too little detail to answer. What would that payment system need to be able to do?

Comment: @Pekka: They're still trying to define themselves...

Comment: @Developer Art: It has always been defined by what it's not, but nobody actually knows what it *is* :) @morandi3: No, seriously: Europe is not nearly as homogeneous as the US in this regard - for example, imagine Maryland having its own payment system, which is not compatible at all with Oregon's, and you specifically mustn't use *that* one in Iowa. Fun fun fun (fortunately, PayPal is *somewhat* global).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question lacks information.

You pick an payment system based on information like:

1. Which countries do I need payment methods for? Which company offers me all these methods so I don't need to implement multiple payment providers.
2. How much value/profit will my average order be, and how much transaction costs am I able to pay?
3. Which system suits the costs I can spare for implementation?
4. Perhaps the payment system has a synergy with my administration system?

without more detailed information, the answer to this question will not be of value.

Answer (score 2):

Well i could recommend Ideal for the Netherlands but other then that paypal, clickandbuy and western union.